# How do I change the structure in the thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, structure

Please help me, I'm completely confused.

How do I make this code work?

I need to change the structure members in the thread...

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    str: String,
    b: bool,
    i: u128,
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec_s = vec![];

    vec_s.push(S {
        str: "a".to_string(),
        b: false,
        i: 0,
    });

    let mut threads = vec![];

    for s in vec_s {
        {
            let mut _s = &s;
            threads.push(std::thread::spawn(move || {
                _s.b = true;
                _s.str = "b".to_string();
                _s.i = 1;
            }));
        }
    }

    for thread in threads {
        let _ = thread.join();
    }

    dbg!(&vec_s);
}
```

The compiler outputs a lot of errors:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `_s.b`, which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:23:17
   |
23 |                 _s.b = true;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign

error[E0594]: cannot assign to `_s.str`, which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:24:17
   |
24 |                 _s.str = "b".to_string();
   |                 ^^^^^^ cannot assign

error[E0594]: cannot assign to `_s.i`, which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:25:17
   |
25 |                 _s.i = 1;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ cannot assign

error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:26
   |
21 |               let mut _s = &s;
   |                            ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
22 |               threads.push(std::thread::spawn(move || {
   |  __________________________-
23 | |                 _s.b = true;
24 | |                 _s.str = "b".to_string();
25 | |                 _s.i = 1;
26 | |             }));
   | |______________- argument requires that `s` is borrowed for `'static`
27 |           }
28 |       }
   |       - `s` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `vec_s`
   --> src/main.rs:34:10
    |
9   |     let mut vec_s = vec![];
    |         --------- move occurs because `vec_s` has type `Vec<S>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
19  |     for s in vec_s {
    |              ----- `vec_s` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
...
34  |     dbg!(&vec_s);
    |          ^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `vec_s`
   --> /home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/collect.rs:261:18
    |
261 |     fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
    |                  ^^^^
help: consider iterating over a slice of the `Vec<S>`'s content to avoid moving into the `for` loop
    |
19  |     for s in &vec_s {
    |              +
```

Comment: "The compiler outputs a lot of errors" what errors? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I think you need to use thread safe Arc https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html

Comment: but anw, why you use thread to change the value of struct? is that intended?

Comment: @giyuu, In reality, there are more members in the structure and there are more structures in the vector. Here I have given the values of such types that need to be changed. The values that need to be filled in are obtained from the network and for speed it would be desirable to do it in separate threads in parallel.

Comment: @cafce25, It does not allow me to post the whole big log with errors here.

Comment: @giyuu, please tell me how I can use Arc with the structure?

Comment: @giyuu You used to require `Arc`, but Rust recently introduced scoped threads, which allows solving this problem using normal references.

Comment: @Evgeny nit: don't use `str` as a variable name, as it is also a Rust keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to do multithreading. Everything accessed by multiple threads has to be thread-safe. Further, with Rust being very strict (zero undefined behaviour tolerance), the compiler has to understand that your code is thread-safe.

The biggest problem here is that Rust's borrow checker doesn't understand that your threads get joined at some point. Therefore it doesn't allow you to create references to your `S` objects, because it cannot prove how long those references exist. Rust must be able to prove that they are destroyed before your `S` object is dropped; that's part of Rust's borrow checker safety guarantees.

For your specific usecase, Rust introduced [thread scopes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html). With them, the compiler can finally understand thread lifetimes.

With some minor ownership issues fixed (use `&mut vec_s` for your loop, otherwise the `vec_s` object gets consumed by the loop), this now works:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    s: String,
    b: bool,
    i: u128,
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec_s = vec![];

    vec_s.push(S {
        s: "a".to_string(),
        b: false,
        i: 0,
    });

    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        let mut threads = vec![];
        for s in &mut vec_s {
            threads.push(scope.spawn(move || {
                s.b = true;
                s.s = "b".to_string();
                s.i = 1;
            }));
        }
        for thread in threads {
            let _ = thread.join();
        }
    });

    dbg!(&vec_s);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:31] &vec_s = [
    S {
        s: "b",
        b: true,
        i: 1,
    },
]
```

---

Another optimization:

If you don't actually use the `JoinHandle`s for error propagation or similar, you don't need them at all in this example. The `scope` already automatically joins all threads it spawned at the end of the scope:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    s: String,
    b: bool,
    i: u128,
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec_s = vec![];

    vec_s.push(S {
        s: "a".to_string(),
        b: false,
        i: 0,
    });

    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        for s in &mut vec_s {
            scope.spawn(move || {
                s.b = true;
                s.s = "b".to_string();
                s.i = 1;
            });
        }
    });

    dbg!(&vec_s);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:27] &vec_s = [
    S {
        s: "b",
        b: true,
        i: 1,
    },
]
```

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't know about std::thread::scope and got thoroughly stuck. Now this task is solved!

Comment: @Evgeny It's quite new and so not many people know about it yet. Before, you had to resort to external libraries (like [rayon's scoped threads](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/fn.scope.html)) or use `Arc<Mutex<S>>` to make every single `S` object thread-safe, which would have introduced some overhead.

Comment: @Evgeny One more thing: you don't actually need the `.join()` calls here. The scope automatically joins all the threads at the end. I added another example to demonstrate it.